# unknown variable declaration

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I've been reading few codes in kaggle and came across a vague implementation. Till today I never knew that we can declare a variable externally for a model.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
...
model = LogisticRegression()
....
model.loss = 0.01
model.penalty = 'l1'
model.l1_ratio = True
model.alpha = 'auto'
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

I know that logistic regression in sklearn doesn't have any of those parameters except for penalty, I've found another linear algorithm SGDClassifier in sklearn itself, which actually accepts all of those parameters but for 'loss', 'l1_ratio', 'alpha' the data types were different. I know the description of each parameter and why they are used in other algorithms but I am unable to understand the reason behind this declaration. Any explanation for this implementation is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you link any article using this behaviour so that we can have a better idea why its being done. From the above code, its of no use (as it will not be used anywhere in sklearn) except for ease of changing the algorithm. Here we can just change `model = LogisticRegression()` to model = GradientBoostingClassifier() without having to worry about declaring them again. Only the relevant params to the model will be changed and rest will be just be there without any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to utilize this type of declaration is for making the code more modular. Something like this:

```
def get_clf(clf_type,loss,penalty):
    my_clf = clf_type
    my_clf.loss = loss
    my_clf.penalty = penalty
    return my_clf
```

Now this can be treated as a generic function to make your code more modular. So whenever you need to create a classifier, you can just call:

```
model = get_clf(LogisiticRegression(),0.01,'l1')
```

So even if you change your regressor, you just need to change the above single line. Again it's all about the personal style of programming and how one is used to it. Some people like to declare the parameters in the definition itself while some do it explicitly like in your question.

Comment: I get that, but since we are declaring and initializing those variables explicitly how will they be used in the algorithm.